# Realm Browserの使い方

Tags: swift, realm

現在`Realm`を使ってデータベースを操作しているのですが、データベースの中身を確認しようと`Realm Browser`なるものを見つけて色々試しているのですが、データベースの中身を見ることができません。そもそもまずRealmを使って生成されたデータベースファイルがどこの場所にあるのかすらもわかりません。どなたか分かる方がいれば`Realm Browser`の使い方を教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### シミュレータの場合

シミュレータの場合、Realmのファイルは

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<simulator-uuid>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<application-uuid>/Documents/default.realm
```

のような場所に保存されます。

#### SimPholders2を使う

この場所を探すのは大変なので、 r.izumita さんが書かれているように[SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com)などのシミュレータのDocumentディレクトリを簡単に探してくれるソフトウェアを利用すると便利です。

[SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com)を利用した場合、次のようにしてRealmのファイルを開くことができます。

[SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com)を起動するとメニューバーにアイコンが表示されます。
メニューをクリックすると、シミュレータにインストールされたアプリの一覧が表示されるので、選択すると、そのアプリのDocumentディレクトリが表示されます。

Realmを使ってデータを保存した場合、普通はそこに`.realm`という拡張子のファイルがあると思いますので、それをRealm Browserにドラッグ＆ドロップします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### コマンドラインから

```
println(realm.path)
```

などとしてRealmファイルの場所をデバッグコンソールに出力して、出力されたパスをコピーして、コマンドラインから、

```
open /Users/katsumi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../Documents/default.realm
```

とすると自動的にそのファイルをRealm Browserで開くことができます。

### デバイスの場合

Xcodeからインストールしたアプリケーションの場合は、デバイスを接続して、Xcodeのメニューから`Window>Devices`と選択するとデバイスの一覧ウインドウが開きます。

アプリがインストールされているデバイスを選択すると、Xcodeからインストールしたアプリの一覧が表示されますので、ファイルを見たいアプリを選択して、`歯車のボタン>Download Container...`を選択すると、アプリのデータがダウンロードされます。

ダウンロードされたデータは`<バンドルID> <タイムスタンプ>.xcappdata`のようなパッケージ形式になっていますので、選択して右クリックから、`パッケージの内容を表示`を選択すると、中身が表示されます。
普通はDocumentディレクトリに`.realm`という拡張子のファイルがあると思いますので、それをRealm Browserにドラッグ＆ドロップします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。デバイスで確認したかったのですが、ご提示の方法で確認するとデータベースの中身を見ることができました！思ったより簡単に確認することができ、感謝しております。誠にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

SimulatorのデータであればFinderでSimulatorのアプリのDocumentsフォルダを開いてdefault.realmファイルをダブルクリックすればRealm Browserで開けます。[SimPholders2](http://simpholders.com/)を使うと簡単に開けます。

実機であれば[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)（有料）やFuse for OSX（ちょっと面倒）等を利用して実機をマウントしてアプリのDocumentsディレクトリのdefault.realmファイルを開けばいいはずです。（試してませんが…）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。シミュレーターでの確認方法が分かりました。ありがとうございます。